# mysql polygons (How to substitude the bounds)

Tags: mysql, geospatial, point-in-polygon

I am storing the bounds returned by google. These are in the form of ne_lat, ne_lng, sw_lat and sw_lng coordinates.

i was looking in mysql ploygons function for some implementation, here is sample function with some sample entries:

GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))')

Can anyone tell me the proper substitution of google returned bounds in the upper polygon function?

I did a bit research and i concluded it to be like:

GeomFromText('Polygon((ne_lat ne_lng,ne_lat sw_lng,sw_lat sw_lng,sw_lat ne_lng,ne_lat ne_lng))')

Did i made proper entries in polygon function??

Thanks in advance!